# Python двойной return

Tags: python

Возможен ли такой код - речь о `return`

```
    @app.route('/')
    def index():
    if 'username' in session:
        return 'Logged in as %s' % escape(session['username'])
        time.sleep(5)
        return render_template('index.html')
    return 'You are not logged in'
    time.sleep(5)
    return render_template('login.html')
```

Если нет, то как реализовать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы выполнить несколько "return", можно использовать [`yield`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/231767/4279):

```
def f():
    yield 1
    yield 2

i = f()
print(next(i))
print(next(i))
```

Вот [пример кода c `flask`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13388915/4279):

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    def g():
        for i, c in enumerate("hello"*10):
            time.sleep(.1)  # an artificial delay
            yield i, c
    return Response(stream_template('index.html', data=g()))
```

Для примера в вопросе, достаточно просто вернуть страницу с `<meta refresh>`, который перенаправляет на `login.html` после паузы:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url={url}/login.html">
```

> **Q:** `<meta refresh>` частично не подойдет, ибо как тогда страница узнает, нужен ли рефреш или нет

`<meta refresh>` эмулирует последние два `return` в примере в вашем вопросе, то есть когда **всегда** перенаправление происходит. Если `<meta refresh>` в `nologin.html`, то вместо двух `return` подставьте `return render_template('nologin.html')`.

Перенаправления не лучший UX создают, желательно рассмотреть варианты, которые этого не требуют. Например, показывать предупреждение прямо на `login.html` странице как это происходит, если [попытаться задать вопрос на Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: `<meta refresh>` частично не подойдет, ибо как тогда страница узнает, нужен ли рефреш или нет

Comment: Большое спасибо за объяснение )

Answer (score 3):

Нет, нельзя. При вызове return вы выходити из функции. Соответственно код, который расположен ниже return будет недостижим.
Если вы хотите вывести на форме какое-то сообщение, то передавайте параметром в форму при вызове render_template, если сохранить, то для этого используют модуль logging.

Comment: немного не понял конца изложения.