# Доступ ко второй вложеной функции извне

Tags: python

Мне известно, что в Python можно получить доступ ко вложенной функции задав значение в переменную, содержащую значение родительской функции, как в функцию. Можно ли подобным образом получить доступ к другим функциям, содержащимся в родительской?

```
def func1(x):
    def func2(y):   
        return x, y 
    def func3(z):   
        return x, z 
    return func2
    return func3

new = func1(x)
#new(y) == funct2(y) - тут показано как доступ можно получить к первой вложенной функции извне
# ?? == func3(z) - вопрос в том как получить доступ ко второй вложеной функции извне (возможно ли это в Python?)
```

Comment: func1 возвращает func2, которая будет сохранена в переменной new. `return func3` никогда не выполнется.

Comment: Это можно сделать, но не нужно практически всегда.  Какую вы задачу пытаетесь решить? Какой контекст? См. [XY-задача](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/709/23044)

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Python двойной return](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/499413/23044)

Comment: Товарищи правящие, то что return-ы вне функции - не правильно, их нужно подтянуть. Но то что их 2 - это так задумано автором вопроса, он про это и спрашивает, не нужно пытаться это "исправить".

Answer (score 2):

Не вполне понятно, что вы хотите.

У вас func2 и func3 получаются абсолютно идентичны. То есть и одна, и другая получают переменную x из родительской функции и ещё какую-то переменную как собственный аргумент, после чего возвращает пару из x и своего аргумента.

То, что в одном случае у вас аргумент называется y, а в другом - z, ничего не меняет, потому что это чисто внутреннее имя функции. Внешне же func2 и func3 будут работать АБСОЛЮТНО одинаково.

Ну и ещё у вас путаница с аргументами. Когда вы объявляете функцию, то действительно можно написать аргументом любое допустимое имя, и не заботиться о том, откуда этот аргумент возьмётся.

Но когда вы вызываете функцию func1(x) вы сначала должны позаботиться о том, чтобы у вас уже существовала переменная x.

Кажется, вы не очень твёрдо понимаете, что такое вообще функции, и как они работают - я советую вам поразбираться в этой теме.

Теперь о вашем вопросе.

Если я всё-таки правильно понял ваше изначальное намерение, и вам нужно иметь некий контейнер с двумя функциями, то это можно сделать через классы.

```
class Func1(object):

    def func2(self, param):
        print('Сработала функция func2 c параметром ' + param)

    def func3(self, param):
        print('Сработала функция func3 с параметром ' + param)

    y = func2
    z = func3


new = Func1()

new.y('3')   # напечатает: Сработала функция func2 c параметром 3
new.z('3')   # напечатает: Сработала функция func3 c параметром 3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def func1(x):
    def func2(y):
        return x, y
    def func3(z):
        return x, z

    yield func2, func3  # fn links

    def func4(a):
        return a, func2(x)

    yield func4(x)  # fn return

f = func1(1)

func2, func3 = next(f)
print(func2(2), func3(3))

f4 = next(f)
print(f4)
```